# How do I calculate in R the percentage of students grouped by race/ethnicity who scored >1 in a column representing a specific assignment in a class?

Tags: r

My data looks something like this but I have about 100+ rows:

| ID | Grade | Race/Ethnicity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | White |
| 2 | 2 | Asian |
| 3 | 2 | Hispanic |
| 4 | 0 | Asian |
| 5 | 3 | Black |
| 6 | 1 | White |
| 7 | 2 | Hispanic |
| 8 | 1 | Black |

I want to calculate the percentage of students grouped by race/ethnicity who scored a grade >1 out of the total number of students who identify as that racial/ethnic group (i.e. how many white students scored a grade >1 out of the total number of white students in the class then repeat for all racial/ethnic categories). I want this with one row per race/ethnic category and the corresponding percent:

| Race/Ethnicity | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| White | 0% |
| Asian | 50% |
| Hispanic | 100% |
| Black | 50% |

I tried the code below:

```
data %>%
  select(`Race/Ethnicity`) %>%
  mutate(Percent = scales::label_percent()(ave(data$Grade>1, data$`Race/Ethnicity`, FUN=mean)))
```

However, it gives me the following output with the repeating values of each race/ethnicity, but I just want one row for each race/ethnicity category:

| Race/Ethnicity | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| White | 0% |
| Asian | 50% |
| Hispanic | 100% |
| Asian | 50% |
| Black | 50% |
| White | 0% |
| Hispanic | 100% |
| Black | 50% |

Comment: Share whatever your data is inside your question by using `dput(data)` instead of these tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~grade, ~race_ethnicity,
   1L,     0L,           "White",
   2L,     2L,           "Asian",
   3L,     2L,        "Hispanic",
   4L,     0L,           "Asian",
   5L,     3L,           "Black",
   6L,     1L,           "White",
   7L,     2L,        "Hispanic",
   8L,     1L,           "Black"
  ) 

data %>%
  group_by(race_ethnicity) %>% 
  summarise(percent = mean(grade > 1)) %>%
  mutate(percent = scales::label_percent()(percent))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  race_ethnicity percent
  <chr>          <chr>  
1 Asian          50%    
2 Black          50%    
3 Hispanic       100%   
4 White          0%
```